# View website on intranet using machine name (as website domain name) of computer hosting website in IIS 7

Tags: iis-7, windows-firewall, intranet, port-80, web-applications

I have a local website running on "localhost" on port 80 in IIS 6.  On Windows XP (machine name WINXPMAC), I'm able to setup IIS 6 so that my local web application is visible on our company network.  I don't even have to set up another binding for it in IIS 6.  In order to do so, I go into the Windows Firewall and let port 80 through.  If I'm on another machine within our intranet domain, I can go to this location to see my web application: http://WINXPMAC/default.aspx.  If I'm on the machine where the web application is being hosted (on WINXPMAC), I can also visit http://localhost/default.aspx to see the site.  However, I recently tried setting this up using Windows 7 and when I allowed port 80 as an incoming and outgoing port (2 different rules) in the Windows 7 Firewall, it did not work.  My machine name in Windows 7 is WIN7-MAC).  I want to be able to view the site on another machine on our intranet as I did with Windows XP.  How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the same concept in Windows 7.  The bindings at the site level are in the Actions pane on the left.  If you want to listen to everything on a server and you only have 1 websites, just leave the IP to (All Unassigned) and the host header blank.  That will catch all traffic.

Also make sure that you can ping the server name and that it resolves to the correct IP.

Here's a short video that will bring you up to speed on this: http://dotnetslackers.com/projects/LearnIIS7/

Comment: Thanks, that worked!  The "host name" field was my issue.  
http://screencast.com/t/STcxxK2yrGlh